# Vue3 controlling the session between API calls

Tags: session, vuejs3

Good morning,
I'm struggling to find a way to solve a problem I have in hands with a Vue3 application:

The application interacts with a SpringBoot API REST in order to do CRUD operations. Those API calls are done by logged users, so the front has a cookie `JSESSIONID` to indicate that the user has a session. The Spring Boot session expires after 30 minutes if the user does not any API call.

What I want is that after the last API call done by the front, the front will activated a countdown of 29 minutes and, after the time has passed, it will show a message to the user indicating the session is about to expire, but if the front does any api call, it should restart the countdown to 29 minutes.

I have been thinking a lot on the problem and I have been searching on internet, but I don't have any ideas.

Have you faced a similar problem? How did you solve it?

PD: I'm not interested in idle solutions where the countdown is restarted when the user press a key or moves the mouse.

Comment: Please read [ask]. You're supposed to document what you tried and why you think what you tried should work. Without a coding attempt your question is not a request for help with programming, it's a request for programming.